# Meaning of 3 byte numeric in mysql (MEDIUMINT)

Tags: mysql, types

[Funny thing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) I've found abount mysql. MySQL has a 3 byte numeric type - MEDIUMINT. Its range is from -8388608 to 8388607. It seems strange to me. Size of numeric types choosen for better performance, I thought data should be aligned to a machine word or double word. And if we need some restriction rules for numeric ranges, it must be external relative to datatype. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
  id INT RANGE(0, 500) PRIMARY KEY
)
```

So, does anyone know why 3 bytes? Is there any reason?

Comment: Interesting question - you got my upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alignment issue you mentioned applies mostly to data in RAM. Nothing forces MySQL to use 3 bytes to store that type as it processes it.

This might have a small advantage in using disk cache more efficiently though.

Comment: Yes, but modern processor doesn't have instructions for operating with 3-bytes data. When taking a sum of 3 byte numbers processor will sum two 4 byte numbers with zerofilled high order byte. Is this correct?

The only advantage I see on 3 byte numbers is space. On large dataset 3-bte numbers will be 25% smaller.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I wouldn't normally use that data type though ;)

Answer (score 9):

The reason is so that if you have a number that falls within a 3 byte range, you don't waste space by storing it using 4 bytes.

When you have twenty billion rows, it matters.

Comment: Space is very important in database operations.

Comment: This doesn't answer the alignment question, which was the point of the original question.

Comment: Mehrdad answered that: the alignment doesn't matter for the purposes I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

We frequently use `tinyint`, `smallint`, and `mediumint` as very significant space savings.  Keep in mind, it makes your indexes that much smaller.

This effect is magnified when you have really small join tables, like:

```
id1 smallint unsigned not null,
id2 mediumint unsigned not null,
primary key (id1, id2)
```

And then you have hundreds of millions or billions of records.

Comment: Processors can't compare 3-bytes numbers. So in memory index should contain 4 bytes on each index position. Are you shure that index size is 3 byte long if you using mediumint?