# Mysql medium int vs. int performance

Tags: mysql, performance, datatable

I have a simple users table, I guess the maximum users I am going to have is 300,000.

Currently I am using:

```
 CREATE TABLE users
 (
         id INT UNSIGNED AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         ....
```

Of course I have many other tables for which users(id) is a FOREIGN KEY.

I read that since the id is not going to use the full maximum of INT it is better to use:
MEDIUMINT and it will give better performance.

Is it true?

(I am using mysql on Windows Server 2008)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157371/meaning-of-3-byte-numeric-in-mysql-mediumint

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would consider using MEDIUMINT sometimes.. on 300K rows.. MEDIUMINT gives u enough room up to 16M rows (unsigned).

It is not only about "smaller table size" when u use indexes.. the difference can be huge
on a 27M rows tables.. changing 2 columns from INT to MEDIUMINT saved me 1GB (indexes + table data) so it went from 2.5GB to 1.5 GB.

Answer (score 5):

That is called micro-optimization and not an issue.
Try to ask (yourself in the first place) performance questions based only on the real experience, not imagination. And **profiling** is always for help to distinguish one from another.

As for the "300k max" - in the real life numbers tend to grow unexpectedly. Why to dig a pitfall for yourself?

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be a performance difference, the only advantage you get is a slightly smaller table size. Anyways, for just 300'000 rows you shouldn't have to care.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about speed micro-optimization then use `int`.

A disk read access will read a block of bytes, so reading 4 bytes will be the same as reading 3 bytes.

But since 3 bytes integers are not native for CPUs, `mediumint` needs to be converted before it can be used (memcpy into a 4/8 bytes integer) causing a overhead, while 4 bytes integers are native for CPUs and can be used directly.